# How to remove span inside span of a partiular Id?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a html code

```
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustomActivity.WorkOrderCategoriesName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
      <span id="CustomActivity_WorkOrderCategoriesName-error" class="">The WorkOrderCategoriesName field is required.</span>
</span>

<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustomActivity.Notes" data-valmsg-replace="true">
      <span id="CustomActivity_Notes-error" class="">The Notes field is required.</span>
</span>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete" data-id="">Delete</button>
```

Now When I Click Delete button I need to remove all the span tag that is inside `text-danger field-validation-valid` tag, but the parent span tag should not be deleted.

Mu jquery code is :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("#delete").click(function () {
                jQuery('.text-danger field-validation-valid div').html('');
            });
});
```

didn't help how can i do this?

Comment: you are missing a dot in `jQuery('.text-danger field-validation-valid div')` also I dont see any div inside the span. Believe it should be `jQuery('.text-danger.field-validation-valid span').remove()`

Comment: Voted close as typo as OP is using `div` instead of `span` and has a space ` ` instead of `.` for class name on same element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need .(dot) to access `text-danger` because its class
2. You need an `click` event on `delete`

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
 
  $(document).on('click','#delete', function(e){
  
     jQuery('.text-danger').find('span').remove();
  });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustomActivity.WorkOrderCategoriesName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
      <span id="CustomActivity_WorkOrderCategoriesName-error" class="">The WorkOrderCategoriesName field is required.</span>
</span>

<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustomActivity.Notes" data-valmsg-replace="true">
      <span id="CustomActivity_Notes-error" class="">The Notes field is required.</span>
</span>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete" data-id="">Delete</button>
```

Comment: 2. OP already has click event `$("#delete").click(`, they don't need event delegation here unless proven otherwise (they're not saying click isn't firing just doesn't do what they want (which isn't helped by trying to find `div` instead of `span`))

Comment: And you can just do `jQuery('.text-danger span').remove();`

Answer (score -1):

There's an easy hack for this.

```
$("spanId").html("");
```

This will set inner html of the span to nothing.

Comment: Op is already using `.html('');` - the problem is the selector (not my downvote...but still)

Comment: Using the span id, would be a none dynamic solution. Something like `jQuery('.text-danger span')` would select all the element regarding of how many there are or if new elements has been created after the script is loaded.